# What is going on in this intro Flask code?

Tags: python, flask, python-import

This is the opening code from [the Flask mega-tutorial.](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

> Let's start by creating a simple init script for our app package (file
>   app/**init**.py):
>
> ```
> from flask import Flask
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
> from app import views
> ```
>
> The script above simply creates the application object (of class
>   Flask) and then imports the views module, which we haven't written
>   yet.

I'm not sure what's going on here. If `app` is an instance of a class, how are we using `import` on it? The line `from app import views` makes no sense to me at all. Could someone help me understand whats going on here? Why would we need to instantiate a class in order to import something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An unfortunate clash of names!  `from app import` refers to **module or package** `app` (created just before this code in the tutorial by `mkdir app` and editing of this `__init__.py` in it), nothing to do with **variable name** `app` which does indeed refer to a class instance.

As the last line of `import this` extolls, namespaces are indeed a great thing -- but when they're used implicitly (as in `from` and `import`, whose namespace is quite separate from a module's) it might be nicer and less confusing to avoid deliberately clashing names anyway... because, if one doesn't, confusion on the reader's part is almost inevitable.  Authors of tutorials should be particularly careful about this!

Comment: Oh that's very clear now, bit of a silly choice on the part of the author! Shouldn't all imports go at the top? Why would he do that after instantiating the app? Not that you're the author but is there any particular reasoning you can think of?